# Animate two UIViews at the same time (sticking together)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

i have searched a lot here but can't seem to find the answer to my question...

I have a class called SubView, this class has a simple ability, it can show up or dissapear animated

it does it like this:

```
-(void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

self.active = YES;

//Make topmost
[self.parentView bringSubviewToFront:self];

if (animated) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = self.originalFrame;
                         if (self.panningBlock) {
                             self.panningBlock(self.contentView.frame);
                         }
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];

}

else {
    self.frame = self.originalFrame;
    if (self.panningBlock) {
        self.panningBlock(self.contentView.frame);
    }
}
```

Where self.originalFrame has stored the original value of the position of the View, the hide portion if really similar

```
-(void)hideAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

self.active = NO;

//Store the frame
CGRect _frame = self.frame;

//Set the view starting point
switch (self.showingLocation) {
    case SubViewShowingLocationRight:
        _frame.origin = CGPointMake(_frame.size.width, _frame.origin.y);
        break;
    case SubViewShowingLocationBottom:
        _frame.origin = CGPointMake(_frame.origin.x, _frame.size.height);
        break;
    case SubViewShowingLocationLeft:
        _frame.origin = CGPointMake(-_frame.size.width, _frame.origin.y);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}


if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = _frame;
                         if (self.panningBlock) {
                             self.panningBlock(self.contentView.frame);
                         }
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];

}
else {
    self.frame = _frame;
    if (self.panningBlock) {
        self.panningBlock(self.frame);
    }
}

[self.delegate didDismissSubView:self];
```

}

////
So the animation occurs at self.frame = _frame and self.frame = self.originalFrame

also i have self.panningBlock, that is a block that the parent view can give (it works so it can adjust himself to the frame change of the subview.. i.e. sub view has a picker, and it appears from bottom, i need to adjust the table view so it isn't obscured by the picker)

An Example of what i do is

```
__weak MapViewController * weakSelf = self;
[weakSelf.placesView setPanningBlock:^(CGRect _frame){

    if (weakSelf.placesView.isActive) {
        CGRect mapFrame = weakSelf.mapView.frame;
        mapFrame.origin.x = _frame.origin.x + _frame.size.width;
        weakSelf.mapView.frame = mapFrame;
    }
    else {
        CGRect mapFrame = weakSelf.mapView.frame;
        mapFrame.origin.x = 0;
        weakSelf.mapView.frame = mapFrame;
    }
}];
```

Here the parent view moves right if the subview appear to give a push like animation

That's all the code needed to understand (this is my first question, so forgive any rambling here)

The point is that the animations won't occur at the same time,
what happens is that the view that is entering enters a little more slow than the parent view
they don't stick together, and i really don't know what to do...

BTW: they do stick together the first time the animation occurs, but no more there after..

any suggestions?

**EDIT**
i now give some images as to explain what happens

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: do forgive the else part of the hide method... it sends self.frame instead self.contentView.frame...it doesn't affect really because i always send animated (i'll change it now)

Comment: It's hard to understand what your all your views are. Can you describe what views you have, and how you want them to move? You mention SubView class, a picker, and a table -- it's not clear how these are working together (or whether they're all contained in the same superview).

Comment: Okay, sure... here the subview class is only a view that has the ability to hide or show appearing from the side, the show and hide method do that, make the origin go left, right or to the bottom to disappear, or recover his original frame to appear, after that the self.panning block is an optional block that the subview call, so that the parent of this view, can adjust itself to the view appearing or disappearing (i.e. the view appear from the left and i want the parent view to move itself to the right to make room for it (like push)... the  content view has the content of the subview thanks!

Comment: the panning block is.. what does the caller do when the subview hides or shows (adjust, etc)... the contentView has the actual content (table view, etc), whilst the normal view is clear... (this was due to a legacy method that i had to maintain) ^^... and i almost forgot... in the last line of code... MapViewController => is the controller that has the view that contains the subview... and weakSelf.placesView IS the subview... so i check if the subview is showing (active) and move to give it space... if it's not i set the origin as 0 to use all the screen :D i forgot to explain that

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause this to work the first time, and not thereafter. I think I would need to see the whole code to make any suggestions as to what to do -- it's too difficult for me to wrap my head around without seeing it in action.

Comment: i can't really give you the whole code (giant) but it really is this... press button => [self.placesView showAnimated:YES] it appears and calls the self.panningBlock that is the last block of code that i give you... it sees that the subview is active... and takes it's frame and sets the mapview (the view that i want to  modify) origin to be the width of the appearing sub view... the panning block is called inside an UIView animation block, so the view appearing + the mapview moving should be in sync (surely i'm mising something important here) thanks for your time :)

Comment: Well, the problem doesn't seem to be because you're using a block, since it works the first time. Does anything jump to a new position when you do it the second time, or is it just that the incoming view moves more slowly?

Comment: everything works fine but, as i think it should work (maybe i'm mistaken) the two images should move whilst sticking together, see edit for images... the first time they stick together, but the second time, they don't... they end up in the correct position together, but when they move, they un-stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this as the answer wasn't reached actually...

The issue here was with.. the total size of the views...

the MAPVIEW sized 100% whilst the tableview sized 80%... i was putting them on the same animation... so they will move differently because they have to cover 1.0 second or so of animation for the entire movement...

This problem is fixed by doing an EXPLICIT ANIMATION... there are some libraries out there... i used one that destroyed my project... so i ended up ditching it... and took a more... patch solution... putting the background color so it masks the movement...

The solution to this problem is using an explicit animation and for each frame... move both views to the same point...

i hope that this "solution" helps the community..